# 1/1/2000 20:00:00 only the time - Javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have this date and time format `1/1/2000 20:00:00` and would like to only get the time in this form `20:00 PM` or `08:00 AM`

How can I format it as hh:mm a to my date?

I get it this way:

```
var momentDate = moment($scope.workshop.hour, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
var jsDate = momentDate.toDate();
jsDate.toLocaleString();
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `var time =  "1/1/2000 20:00:00".split(" ")[1].substring(0,5)`

Comment: Why not just use the Moment `.format()` method with a format that only includes the time of day?

Comment: Also in `20:00 PM` the AM/PM is redundant; there's no `20:00 AM`.

Comment: Why do you use `toDate` and `toLocaleString`  instead using the [.format()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) of momentjs?

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for your help, .format () I worked

Answer (score 0):

Try format with `HH:mm A` as an argument. The `A` argument will display capital AM or PM as appropriate. Here's an example to get the current time into that format.

```
var date = new Date()
var momentDate = moment(date);
momentDate.format('HH:mm A')
```

**Updated**

Updated to match OP's request.

Comment: The OP wants the *time of day*, not month-day-year.

Comment: You're correct, I updated my answer to better match his request.